# Is this error message correct: non-type template argument is not a constant expression

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer, constexpr

The following program compiles with GCC 5.2, but not with clang 3.6:

```
constexpr bool flag();

template <bool b = flag()>
constexpr bool test() 
{ 
    return b;
}

int main() 
{
}
```

The error message I get with clang is:

```
main.cpp:3:20: error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression
template <bool b = flag()>
                   ^~~~~~
main.cpp:3:20: note: undefined function 'flag' cannot be used in a constant expression
main.cpp:1:16: note: declared here
constexpr bool flag();
               ^
main.cpp:4:16: error: no return statement in constexpr function
constexpr bool test() 
               ^
```

My question is: Who's right? Or, in other words: Is the program ill-formed?

Comment: Can confirm this, even clang 3.7 doesn't compile it. However, if you put a return statement into `constexpr bool flag()`, it works.

Comment: I think this relates to your other question about the point where default template arguments are evaluated: If they're evaluated at the point of definition, then clang cannot prove that this template is ill-formed under [temp.res]p8

Comment: Why do you have a return statement in a void function?  I can also confirm that this compiles on MSVS 2015

Comment: @dyp But why not? At the point of definition `flag` is not defined and so it should be ill formed. Maybe I'm not understanding what you said.

Comment: To avoid misunderstandings, I changed the return type of the function `test()` from `void` to `bool`. I copied the wrong version of the code. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Sorry, I was slightly confused. There can of course be valid specializations of this template. So the question is, if you can supply an invalid default template argument. This is touched by [CWG 2008](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue2008) as well as [CWG 1850](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1850), but I don't see it fully answered. There is a similar issue in [member templates](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5d45a543a7d6074), which suggests that clang is allowed to reject the OP's program.

Comment: I'm sure glad I don't write C++ compilers for a living.

Comment: @dyp defect 1850 seems to clash with section `14.7.1` *[temp.inst]* which without this defect seems to make this well-formed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say that clang is right:

From the Standard:

[temp.param] 14.1 #9

> 9 A default template-argument is a template-argument (14.3) specified after = in a template-parameter. [...]

And [temp.arg.nontype] 14.3.2

> 1 A template-argument for a non-type template-parameter shall be a converted constant expression (5.20) of the type of the template-parameter.

And [expr.const] 5.20

> 2 A conditional-expression e is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of e, following the rules of the abstract machine (1.9), would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> [...]
>
> (2.3) — an invocation of an undefined constexpr function or an undefined constexpr constructor;

Since `flag()` is declared but not defined, it is not a constant expression and 14.3.2 is violated.

Answer (score 4):

According to ISO C++14 Standard 5.19.2:

> A conditional-expression e is a core constant expression unless the
>   evaluation of e, following the rules of the abstract machine (1.9),
>   would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> - this (5.1.1), except in a constexpr function or a constexpr constructor that is being evaluated as part of e;
> - an invocation of a function other than a constexpr constructor for a literal class, a constexpr function, or an implicit invocation
>     of a trivial destructor (12.4) [ Note: Overload resolution (13.3) is applied as usual — end note ];
> - **an invocation of an undefined constexpr function** or an undefined constexpr constructor;
> - (...)
>     Blockquote

The result of any constexpr function call made prior to it definition is not a constant expression.

Finally it seems that it is GCC bug.

Comment: I think everyone agrees on that. There are some additional questions though, the main one probably is: is clang allowed to reject this program *even though the default template argument is never used*?

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp I know you had to deal with this for your smeta techniques, but I can't remember where this info comes from. Is it from a draft, discussion, defect report, ..?

Comment: @dyp I'm quite sure I address the particular wording in one of the posts at http://b.atch.se - I'm currently on the subway but can provide details on the matter (including an answer) when I get home (hopefully).

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp All I could find is wording for *default template arguments of variable templates* (in a recent draft).